# C# iterate backwards over date

Tags: c#, date, loops, days

I am looking for a C# solution that will allow me to iterate backwards over a date.
Starting at the current date or provided date I would like to loop over the date subtracting one day each time through the loop for a given number of days.  It should of course be able to detect when the month has changed or it is a leap year etc., and return the date in MM-DD-YYYY format.

Comment: Just to double check - are you doing something in the loop, or are you just looking for a date subtract function?

Comment: I want to do something in the loop for each day/date that I count backwards for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be easy enough:

```
var givenNumberOfDays = 30;
for( DateTime day = DateTime.Now; day > DateTime.Now.AddDays( -givenNumberOfDays); day = day.AddDays(-1) )
{
  //perform your logic here
  var dateInCorrectFormat = day.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> Dates(int nDays)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    yield return dt;
    for(int i=0;i<nDays-1;i++)
    {
        dt = dt.AddDays(-1);
        yield return  dt;
    }

}

foreach (var dt in Dates(10))
{
     Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this would iterate backwords:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myDate.AddDays(-i).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Why introduce two "loop variables", myDate and i, when myDate alone is enough?

Comment: I personally find this more readable than jamming it all into the 'for ()' brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dateadd function, that let you add or subtract an interval of time to/from a date and returning the resulting date.
In your case, the interval is "d" (day).
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1zcctd2.aspx).